# how to get output of awk into array in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am comparing two files and displaying the lines which are not similar,
when I just keep

```
echo $(awk 'FNR==NR{f[$0]+=1; next} !($0 in f)' $file1 $file2)
```

I am able to get the values.

When I try to do the same by passing into array , I am getting ":command not found" error

```
declare -a myarr=()
myarr=$("$(awk 'FNR==NR{f[$0]+=1; next} !($0 in f)' $file1 $file2 )")
```

Please help , thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing `+=1`? Nothing in your code uses it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes plus the leading dollar:

```
myarr=$("$(awk 'FNR==NR{f[$0]+=1; next} !($0 in f)' $file1 $file2 )")
```

should be

```
myarr=($(awk 'FNR==NR{f[$0]+=1; next} !($0 in f)' $file1 $file2))
```

Check:

- [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html)
- [Double Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)
- [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html)

---

Btw, your awk command won't print lines which are unique to file1. Probably the `comm` command is what you want, but note that `comm` expects sorted input:

```
comm -13 <(sort "${file1}") <(sort "${file2}")
```